# Adding packages to Pycharm on a windows machine without internet

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda, theano

I recently started working with python and installed Pycharm on my workplace machine which does not have internet. I do have another machine connected to the internet where no IDE/ software can be installed. The standard installation of pycharm had some of the packages already installed. I am in need of packages like tensorflow/ theano, can someone help me with a method to add these packages to Pycharm on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a transfer. In the lack of an internet connection, it can be tiring, but is not impossible.

To make it seamless follow the suggestions given below

1. First prioritize the packages you need to use. So, that you have a clear idea of what you need to transfer.
2. Based on the packages, determine the dependencies. Thus, if package A must be installed before installing package B, then package A is the dependency of package B.
3. Once you have the list of all packages and their dependencies, then considering that you are on windows machine and all the packages you need are open-source, go to their repository on Github or elsewhere, and carefully read the instructions for compiling them.
4. Then take a storage device and transfer the files to your system through it. Compile the dependencies and packages and be done with it.

Comment: Hi Ujjwal thank you for the reply, can you please elaborate how to compile the dependencies and packages.

Comment: It depends upon what you want to compile and what is missing. There is no simple answer. You need to refer to individual package's installation instructions.

Comment: there was no need of deleting your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247579/how-to-convert-a-python-list-containing-a-list-of-arrays-to-a-1xn-numpy-array?noredirect=1#comment91443318_52247579). Just undelete it and I will upvote

Comment: It is okay. I  am not here for upvotes. An answer was already there and there was no need for duplicate answers. All is good.