# How to convert a python List containing a list of arrays to a 1xn numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list as shown below:- ( print output)

```
  port_list=    [array(['51175-80,', '51176-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51259-80,', '51260-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51096-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51079-80,', '51080-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51765-80,', '51766-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51402-80,', '51403-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51235-80,', '51236-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['51381-80,', '51382-80,'],
  dtype='<U9'), array(['44647-40000,'],
  dtype='<U12')]
```

I want to convert this to an numpy array as follows:-

```
[['51175-80,' '51176-80,' '51259-80,' '51260-80,'...]]
```

How can I do this?

Thanks a ton for any help here.

Comment: you are looking for `np.hstack(port_list)` or even `np.concatenate(port_list,axis=None)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: @RafaelC there is an addition of one more axis here, so I tend to believe its really not a duplicate

Comment: Since some arrays have 2 elements, and others 1, ordinary `nparray(yourlist)` results in a 1d object dtype array.  `hstack` can combine the arrays into one 1d array (`U12` dtype).  Making it (1,n) just requires a common numpy reshape.  But do you really want (1,n) instead of (n,)?

Comment: @Onyambu Fair enough, but it is easily adaptable I believe.

Comment: Thank you all of you for your response. @Onyambu, on using hstack, I get a completely flattened array (1,16) but instead I want to get (1,9)  keeping the inner arrays intact  minus the dtype='<U9'. Is it possible ?.